# Unexpected Behaviour of LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am attempting to solve a problem on Hacker Rank that requires the use of `LinkedList`, and I found something strange. The goal is to print the `LinkedList` in reverse.

I have tried debugging the program, but I'm unable to find anything wrong.

In the first piece of code below, I'm only able to put the first and last elements of the `LinkedList` into an `ArrayList`.

```
static void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    List<Integer> tempList = null;

    if (head == null)
        return;
    else {
        tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        tempList.add(head.data);
        while(head.next != null)
            head = head.next;
        tempList.add(head.data);
    }
    System.out.println("Size of the List -"+tempList.size());
    for(int i = tempList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println("Index +"+i+" "+tempList.get(i));
}
```

In the following piece of code, I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` and I am unable to understand what is actually causing this error.

```
static void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    List<Integer> tempList = null;

    if (head == null)
        return;
    else {
        tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(head.next != null)
            tempList.add(head.data);
        head = head.next;
    }
    tempList.add(head.data);
    System.out.println("Size of the List -"+tempList.size());
    for(int i = tempList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println("Index +"+i+" "+tempList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: The first piece of code does exactly what you said, and its behaviour is exactly as expected. You add the first element, traverse to the last elementt, and add that. In the second piece of code you keep adding the same data to the list forever without any terminating condition, so again it is behaving exactly as expected. Unclear why you wild avr any other expectation in either case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use brackets around your code blocks.

```
static void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode head) { 
    List tempList = null;

    if (head == null)
        return;
    else{
        tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(head.next != null) {
            tempList.add(head.data);
            head = head.next;
        }
    }
    tempList.add(head.data);
    System.out.println("Size of the List -"+tempList.size());
    for(int i = tempList.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.println("Index +"+i+" "+tempList.get(i));   

}
```

Your code was such that the while-loop was only a single statement: `tempList.add(head.data);`

The progression statement `head = head.next;` was not part of the loop. So your loop was infinite. That's why you're getting the OOM error. I just added brackets.

EDIT: Same goes for the first method. It's not adding anything to the list - just going through the linked list (Add brackets there too)

Comment: Thanks. It is just a silly mistake. Cant believe i spent hours trying to solve this.